# Drupal 7 > Print Module > print links missing on custom module and views

Tags: drupal-7, view

Print links are missing on my custom module which creates a custom form. Print links are also missing on my custom views. I searched the internet and people pointed me to configuration menu for print module to look there and check "Show link in system(non content) pages. I did that and I even activated it for all pages with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the [Print module](http://drupal.org/project/print) only outputs links on node pages. I also found the following on the module page

> *This module allows you to generate the following printer-friendly
>   versions of any node.*

What I sometimes do to solve this is to make a custom block, which takes the page URL and prepend `/print`. E.g.

```
<?php $current_url = getenv('REQUEST_URI'); ?>
<img src='/sites/all/modules/print/icons/print_icon.png'>
<a href='/print<?php print $current_url; ?> '>Printer-friendly version</a>
```

[Source of example](https://drupal.org/comment/7926201#comment-7926201)

Comment: How do I do that? (take page URL and append /print)

Comment: Edited my answer with an example. Also take a look at the source of the example; it refers to a issue thread where multiple solutions are suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but when I tried to use the provided example I get a error message:

Page not found

The requested page "/print/sql/my_module/form" could not be found.

Comment: And if you try with menu path you provided in custom module by hook_menu?

Comment: As in...? Error messages? Could you also add the relevant part of your custom module in your first post?